# Percent Total in a Textbox

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column that calculates the percentages of a row base on expression. The expression is:

```
=Fields!LineNo.Value/Sum(Fields!LineNo.Value, "dsKPIs")*100
```

Which actually returns the right value.

And now When I added a total row from the Row Group pane through the Detail level as there are no group involve in the report, no total was added.

I have tried using `ReportItems`, `RunningValue` but unable to add a total to the report without the error "...aggregate function can only be used on report items contained in a page header and footer." My expression was:

```
=SUM(ReportItems!txtPctTotal.Value)
```

How do I add up the column containing the first expression above?

Comment: What happens when you try something like `=Sum(Fields!LineNo.Value)/Sum(Fields!LineNo.Value, "dsKPIs")*100` ?

Comment: Thanks Ian for the reply. That will give me the overall total of the the field. What I actually want to achieve is find the percentage of the all the column. For example let say I have 20,1, 10,and 15 as values in column from each role as a result of the expression =Fields!LineNo.Value/Sum(Fields!LineNo.Value, "dsKPIs")*100. Now, I equally want to have the percent of these in my total( that is the running percent of 20,1, 10,and 15. How do I get this done? Thank you

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but are you able to add some sample data and your expected results to the question? I'm still having a bit of trouble imagining what the final result should be.